# Do we have a compiler for RISC-V vector instructions now?

Tags: riscv

Do we have a compiler for RISC-V vector instructions now? I have searched online and it seems we still don't have one.

Comment: Looks like someone is at least working on a branch of the riscv-gcc repository to support rvv-0.7.x. https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gcc/tree/rvv-0.7.x

Answer (score 0):

It seems like on various RISC-V cores there are some jobs done already. Like PULP from ETH Zurich, Università di Bologna, they design SIMD-like extensions and also have corresponding GCC with modifications.

Answer (score 0):

There is some preliminary work done on LLVM: https://github.com/rkruppe/rvv-llvm and there are multiple custom extensions that do similar things but are not following the (not yet frozen) standard. Most notably the [RI5CY](https://github.com/pulp-platform/riscv) core from the PULP project has been used not only in academia but also commercial ASICs like on the gapuino (GAP8) and VEGABoard (RV32M1) that can be used with a GCC port.

Also, see some pointers regarding upstream and SiFive GCC support for the V extension [here](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain/issues/460).